# Is this the proper way to complete a handshake for pyOpenSSL?

Tags: python, openssl, handshake, pyopenssl

There seems to be a surprising lack of information or documentation regarding how this process works which makes it difficult for me to determine if I'm seeing proper behavior or not. I found the state_string() call which gives me strings such as these:

before/connect initialization
SSLv3 read server hello A
SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSLv3 read server key exchange A
SSLv3 read finished A

which aren't particularly helpful if I'm not sure the proper order. To me it looks right but the problem is that the methodology I use to advance through these states feels wrong. I found this code snippet elsewhere:

```
while True:
    try:
        ssl_conn.do_handshake()
        break()
    except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:
        pass
```

Is this the proper way to set up OpenSSL? Just force do_handshake() until it stops throwing a WantReadError?

I've also noticed that a call to shutdown() and close() on this socket sends RSTs instead of the usual FIN, ACKs of TCP. Is that proper behavior?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, that does appear to be an appropriate way to force the handshake. The reason this was required in my part is because I'm using an interface that happens to be slower than directly connecting. With a short sleep in the except I was able to get the handshake with minimal calls and confirmed that the connection is up as I can send data.

As for my second question, the answer is no that the RSTs are not proper behavior. This was due to my configuration so that my middleman couldn't find the server to route to and was throwing the RSTs. Proper behavior is the typical FIN,ACKs of TCP close().